# How to friend template class function

Tags: c++

I am trying to declare a specific function in a template class as a friend.

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    // Constructor, destructor, etc..

    void update();
}

// This is the function I'm trying to declare as a friend
template <class T> void A<T>::update()
{
    // Do stuff, accessing private members of B
}
```

The class I'm trying to provide friend access:

```
class B
{
// Here is where I can't figure out how to declare A::update() as a friend function
}
```

I was able to successfully declare all of A as a friend with:

```
// Forward declare at top
template class<T>
class A;

// Then inside of class B
template <class T> friend class A;
```

However, I'm trying to restrict access to B's private/protected scope inside of only A::update().

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want every instantiation of `A<T>::update()` to be a friend of `B`?

Comment: @JustinTime Because it uses one of the private functions in B. I don't want to needlessly expose this function as public, because it's only intended to be used by A.

Comment: No, I mean, why do you want _every_ `A<T>::update()` to be a friend of `B`, instead of just (for example) `A<B>::update()`?  Does `B` specifically require that every `A<T>::update()` be allowed free reign, or is it possible to narrow it down to only one or a few `T`s?

Comment: Either way, it appears [this is just a Clang bug](https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=28404) starting with [version 3.6](https://godbolt.org/g/ZHW3lv), and that the code itself is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    void update();
};

class B
{
private:
    int asd;
    template <class T> friend void A<T>::update();
};

template <class T> void A<T>::update()
{
    B test;
    test.asd = 2;
}
```

Comment: This compiles but I get this warning: `dependent nested name specifier 'A<T>::' for friend class declaration is not supported; turning off access control for 'B' [-Wunsupported-friend]
   friend void A<T>::update();
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^`

Comment: @btse Try to put B class definition before update method definition, worked for me with clang. Before I got same error as you.

Comment: Sorry I should have been a bit clearer, the two classes are defined in separate files. Class A includes Class B's header file, class B's file has the forward declaration of the template class A.

Comment: @btse In most cases when you working on templates, the better idea is to keep you methods definitions with its declarations (in *.h files). You should read this articles: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-class-defn-from-decl

Comment: @marcias Template class A is declared and defined in a single header file. Class B is declared and defined in two separate files. Class B is not a template class, I just want to provide friend access to A's update() function.